# Why is Magento trying to call in the Mage namespace rather than my custom namespace?

Tags: php, magento

I’ve created a module within the local code folder in our custom namespace.
The block isn’t displaying on the frontend, and on checking the exception log, it turns out Magento is looking in the wrong place.

> ```
> exception ‘Mage_Core_Exception’ with message ‘Invalid block type:
> Mage_MyCompany_ForthcomingProducts_Block_List’
> in /var/www/html/app/Mage.php:407
> ```

The same also goes if I exclude the MyCompany_ prefix when calling the block; it still looks in the Mage namespace.
I have this in a file called MyCompany_All.xml in the modules folder, and the CMS layouts I’ve added are working fine, so Magento is definitely loading it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_CmsLayouts>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </MyCompany_CmsLayouts>
        <MyCompany_ForthcomingProducts>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </MyCompany_ForthcomingProducts>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what’s causing this?

---

Added: The block is being called by a static block with this template code:

```
{{block type="MyCompany_ForthcomingProducts/List" template="forthcomingproducts/list.phtml"}}
```

And the config.xml for the block is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <MyCompany_ForthcomingProducts>
                <version>0.9</version>
            </MyCompany_ForthcomingProducts>
        </modules>

        <global>
            <blocks>
                <forthcomingproducts>
                    <class>MyCompany_ForthcomingProducts_Block</class>
                </forthcomingproducts>
            </blocks>
       </global>
    </config>
```

Comment: I think the layout.xml or code where this block is called is the relevant place to look. To diagnose, I'd want to see that, and perhaps the config.xml for the block in question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I've added the information to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adjusting your block declaration as follows:

```
{{block type="forthcomingproducts/list" template="forthcomingproducts/list.phtml"}}
```

In your config file you defined an alias for your blocks (`forthcomingproducts`) and now you should follow it. Magento will dereference `forthcomingproducts` to be `MyCompany_ForthcomingProducts_Block` as you requested, then append the capitalized class name (`list`), creating the classname `MyCompany_ForthcomingProducts_Block_List`. When you use a alis that Magento doesn't know about (`MyCompany_ForthcomingProducts` in your example), it is assumed to be part of the Mage namespace.

Hope that helps,
Joe

Comment: Thanks Joe! Magento has stopped throwing an exception now, so I'm assuming it's found the module. Having another issue but I'll see if I can solve it first!